# List index out of range,python troubleshooting

Tags: python-2.7

```
for i in range(0,len(text_list)):
    if (text_list[i] == "!" and text_list[i+1].isupper()):
        print "something"
    else:
        text_list.pop(i)
```

`Traceback` (most recent call last):

```
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    if (text_list[i]=="!" and text_list[i+1].isupper()):
```

**Error:**

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I want to remove all the exclamation marks from a text file that are not at the end of a sentence.

Comment: It's not clear which part of the problem is confusing to you. If you just Google the error message I'm sure you would find an answer.

Comment: First of all, if text_list is a string and not a list, you cannot use pop. Secondly , if your condition is an exclamation mark followed by a non capital letter, that is easily solvable with regex.

Answer (score 0):

When your i will become last index of the text_list then "text_list[i+1].isupper()" will give you error because i+1 will be out of index range. You can do something like this :

```
for i in range(0,len(text_list)):
    if(i!=len(text_list-1)):
        if (text_list[i]=="!" and text_list[i+1].isupper()):                
            print "something"   
        else:
            text_list.pop(i)
```

Comment: Why not `range(0, len(text_list) -1)` instead of  `if (i != len(text_list - 1)) ?

Comment: Ya that's also right, infact using `range(0, len(text_list) -1)` will be a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

When `i` becomes `len(text_list) - 1`, `i + i` is out of bounds. This is your first problem. The second problem is that you are popping within the for loop. This changes the size of the list.

I suggest to save the indices to be removed in a separate list, and then pop them after the loop is finished.

```
to_remove = []

for i in range(0,len(text_list) - 1):
    if (text_list[i]=="!" and text_list[i+1].isupper()):                
        print "something"   
    else:
        to_remove.append(i)

for i in reversed(to_remove):
    text_list.pop(i) # use del if you don't need the popped value
```